# Understanding insertion of PNG file into a C# project

Tags: c#

Below lines of code are working with the .jpg file format.

I want .png to be also read upon inputting something in a textbox.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Users\A\Desktop\TACLC\Images\" + textBox1.Text + ".jpg"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Image not found", "Error Message Prompt", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        Main objs = new Main();
        if (objs == null)     {
            objs.Parent = this;     }
        objs.Show();
        this.Hide();     }
    else     {
        Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\A\Desktop\TACLC\Images\" + textBox1.Text + ".jpg");
        this.pictureBox3.Image = image;     }     }[![Their are 4 errors occured but manage to make it 3 (I put ; after the null). First error, null says Type expected. Second error is the "}" before the else and it says Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as statements. Third error in else and it says "Invalid expression term 'else'][1]][1]
```

Comment: Also, if `objs == null`, setting it's `Parent` isn't going to work...

Comment: It seems that you should stop fixing the extension to ".jpg" and let the file name be entered freely including the extension. That way, you'll be able to use images in all formats supported by System.Drawing.Image.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of the files you want to look for and then check to see if any of them exists:

```
string dirPath = @"C:\Users\A\Desktop\TACLC\Images";
var filesToLookFor = new[]
{
    Path.Combine(dirPath, textBox1.Text + ".jpg"),
    Path.Combine(dirPath, textBox1.Text + ".png")
};

string foundFilePath = filesToLookFor.FirstOrDefault(s => File.Exists(s));
if (foundFilePath is null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Image not found", "Error Message Prompt", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    // Rest of the code.
}
else
{
    Image image = Image.FromFile(foundFilePath);
    this.pictureBox3.Image = image;
}
```

That being said, it's really not a good idea to put that code under `textBox1_KeyPress` as it will get triggered every time the user changes one character in the TextBox. Consider executing this code on a button click or something. Alternatively, you may execute the code on `KeyDown` but only when a certain key is pressed. For example:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // Code goes here.

        e.SuppressKeyPress = true; // Prevent beep sound.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ICloneable i'm using RFID that's why I did that code under event KeyPress and after swiping the ID's only the .jpg file formats are readable that's why i'm asking how to do that in .png also.

Comment: Also i've tried to use the code that you provided above. Theirs some error that i've encountered. Ill be posting it the image

Comment: Okay, let me know what the error says and I'll try to help you further.

Comment: Hi. I already posted the image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJNcG.png. This is the image and the description is on the description as will. I haven't seen the link of the image so I put the link in here.

Comment: @JohnSanityCOPH As a first step, you need to remove the `;` after `if (foundFilePath is null)`.